# monthdays2calendar from calendar module renders OverflowError if year == 1

Tags: python, calendar

I have following function

```
import calendar
def some_function(year):
    y = calendar.Calendar(year)
    print list(y.monthdays2calendar(year, 1))
```

When I call `some_function(1)`, python says `bla-bla-bla OverflowError: date value out of range`

Thanks in advance for clue.

Comment: Yup, it does. So what is your question, exactly? Note that `calendar.Calendar()` does not take a *year* as the argument, it takes the *first weekday*, `0` or `6`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `year` to `calendar.Calendar()`; the class interprets that argument as *firstweekday* and only accepts `0` (Monday) to `6` (Sunday) as the values.

Pass in `0` and the code works just fine:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> y = calendar.Calendar(0)
>>> list(y.monthdays2calendar(1, 1))
[[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6)], [(8, 0), (9, 1), (10, 2), (11, 3), (12, 4), (13, 5), (14, 6)], [(15, 0), (16, 1), (17, 2), (18, 3), (19, 4), (20, 5), (21, 6)], [(22, 0), (23, 1), (24, 2), (25, 3), (26, 4), (27, 5), (28, 6)], [(29, 0), (30, 1), (31, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6)]]
```

That said, there is a problem here with values over `0`, as for year == 1 there appears to be a boundary problem in the module. A [similar bug for the year 9999](http://bugs.python.org/issue15421) was fixed before; I've [filed a new bug for this one](http://bugs.python.org/issue26650).

Comment: It works fine for me with days other than 0 or 6, and you don't get any errors for years after 1 AD. And if you pass in 6 you still get the error.

Comment: @Selcuk: yup, noticed that too; I'm looking further into this.

Comment: Looks like a bug with `calendar` implementation. To calculate the week numbers for AD1 it tries going back one year and fails since year 0 is not defined in proleptic Gregorian Calendar. It only works when the week starts with Sunday since Jan 1, 1 is Sunday.

Comment: @Selcuk: but 0 is Monday, not Sunday. Still, this is a boundary error for year == 1, there was a similar problem with year == 9999. I'm filing a bug report.

Comment: My bad, Jan 1, 1 is Monday in proleptic Gregorian calendar as `calendar.weekday(1, 1, 1)` returns `0`.